# Having issues with script causing freeze

Tags: function, return

I've been rewriting this script I've taken over for awhile now and have spent so many hours sifting through all the lines cleaning it up. I'm still getting freezes in the game post-match after script usage. I thought I fixed all of the syntax and if statements, but apparently it's still having the same freezing issues after usage. Here's the section of the script I've narrowed it down to to save everyone's time.

```
-- does include gold of recipes
function EconPanel.GetEcon(hero)
local totalEcon = 0
local slotNum = 9
for i = 0, slotNum-1 do
    myItem = NPC.GetItemByIndex(hero, i) -- index starts from 0
    if myItem then
        itemName = Ability.GetName(myItem)
        if EconPanel.item2price[itemName] then -- database includes all itemName, such as recipes.
            totalEcon = totalEcon + EconPanel.item2price[itemName]
        end
    end
end

return totalEcon
end

return EconPanel
```